# Changing SlideSize in PowerPoint Using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I am working on a VBA Code converting my numerous excel worksheets to a powerpoint presentation. The code works fine but I need to convert my SlideSize to A4 format for printing. For creating the presentation i am using a template of my company. When I create a new PPT from this template it is always in A4. When my code creates one it is in 4:3.
Changing the SlideSize in PageSetup doesn't work.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
Dim oPP As Object
Dim oPPT As Object
Dim oPPTslide As Object

Set oPP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
oPP.Visible = True
Set oPPT = oPP.Presentations.Add
oPPT.ApplyTemplate {Template Name and Path}
oPPT.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeA4Paper
```

I always get an error *PageSetup.SlideSize: Invalid enumeration value.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using late binding to automate PowerPoint then you will have to define the constant.

`Const ppSlideSizeA4Paper = 3`